# use .htaccess redirection to connect to vpn

Tags: .htaccess, vpn, redirect

I am trying to connect to a VPN connection using an automatic redirection via a `.htaccess` redirection, so the vpn setup is a bit more user-friendly using an url instead of an ip address.

The thing is that, when using the ip directly, all works smoothly. However, using `.htaccess` which redirects to my public IP address throws an `Error 868`.

My `.htaccess` is very basic - all I do is forward the input to the public IP without any filter:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ my.public.ip.address$1
```

The reason I am trying this is that I have successfully setup VPN via sub-domain redirecting to the public IP, so I'm wondering why the `.htaccess` redirection wouldn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Your **my.public.ip.address** is not prefixed with either **http://** or **https://** also you could do with a few flags: **[R,L]** where: R = redirect (browser rather than an invisible server side internal job) and L = last flag to trigger immediate execution, also you don't need your regular expression, anyway try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .*    https://11.22.33.44%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Tried it as well, without success.
Note that on the VPN setup, I tried connection using both `http://my_host.com/location_of_htaccess` and version without `http://` (I also tried the `https` version, without success...)

Comment: what IP based URL works for the VPN at present? As you want to redirect to that one.

Comment: For now, only the IP works fine for my address in this current context - I didn't set-up sub-domain forwarding for this particular example. Could it be the reason of it not working - some DNS setting on the VPN host ?

Comment: Please alter the [R,L] to [R=301,L] and confirm the URL, shown in the browser bar, after requesting the VPN by domain name, is that of the working (if directly requested) VPN.  If it isn't please give the HTTP status code / message you're seeing e.g.  403 Forbiden, 500 Internal Server Error, 503 Service Unavailable

Comment: Getting there - I've place the .htaccess in some sub-folder and access it via `www.mysite.com/folder` - redirected url is `http://my.public.i.p./folder/`. What I need for VPN to work is make the redirection (including port number) to the ip, correct ?