# use .htaccess as dns redirector

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, vpn

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074593/use-htaccess-redirection-to-connect-to-vpn/32077119?noredirect=1#comment52052387_32077119), I tried to achieve a VPN redirection using a `.htaccess` file.

My idea: have a service that automatically updates the `.htaccess` file when my public IP changes - i.e. use this as a dynamic dns workaround.

Now, I am quite new to web programming in general so I don't really know if this attempt even makes sense at all.

If it does make sense what should my `.htaccess` file look like and what would be, on the VPN client side, the server address to enter ?

For a simple example, let's use these assumptions:

1. My web-site is `www.my-site.com`
2. The location of .htaccess file is `www.my-site.com/my_vpn/.htaccess`
3. My public IP is `1.2.3.4` (the vpn server with port-forwading correctly configured)
4. on the VPN client, it is working if connecting with `1.2.3.4`as a server name - but of course, there's no dynamics in this. I would like to use something like `www.my_site.com/my_vpn/` here, so that on the client side, nothing changes...

Comment: I didn't think .htaccess was re-read unless you restarted the pertinent HTTP process

Comment: I cannot make sense out of what you just said. Could you please clarify?

Comment: My previous comment is incorrect: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html.